# ASP.NET Core with Duende IdentityServer - how to clear cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session-cookies, angular11, duende-identity-server

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC Application using Duende IdentityServer for authentication and also have an Angular SPA that is launched once a user is authenticated.

After user logs out I am trying to clear cookies as follows on the server side.

```
foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
{
       Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
}
```

However if another user logs in again on the same tab or another tab or even a new browser session, previous users data is still in the session cookie that the application uses.
Do I have to expire the cookie first.
When I check the Request.Cookies I still see them in there so when a new tab is opened or a new browser is started is the cookies sent back from the Server?
Will they not be removed when the previous user logs out?

Comment: If you want to delete the cookie inside the MVC application, I suggest you could try these codes: `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme);`.

Comment: Hi Brando thanks for your reply. What would be the Identity Server Constants